# How can I calculate the Ethash of a Block

Tags: ethash

Given a particular block number, how can I calculate the Ethash used by this block?

Answer (score 1):

For calculating the Ethash you need a lot more than just the block number (you need the entire header). The documentation about how this is calculated can be seen [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash).

You can copy paste the python code provided in the documentation in a file and pass the block header to the hashimoto_light function defined to calculate the Ethash. This needs no extra packages other than bare Python 3 so it should be easy to run and play with.

Hope this helps